# boost::lexical_cast and stringification of non-builtin types

Tags: c++, templates, boost, stringify, lexical-cast

I have a (maybe) simple problem about boost::lexical_cast with composite types (in my case `std::vector`.

My first version of a templatized stringification function was the following

```
template <typename T>
std::string stringiy(const T &t)
{
std::ostringstream o;
o<< t;
return o.str();
}
```

and a working example was the following:

```
vector<int> x(10,-3;
cout << stringify<vector<int> >(x) << endl;
```

with the output
    `"-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3"~`
but for performance reasons I want to exploit the `boost::lexical_cast`

Now I changed the function implementation:

```
template <typename T>
std::string stringiy(const T &t)
{
   return boost::lexical_cast<string>(t);
}
```

while this method works for built-in types, it stops working for cases like the previous one, when it's used for `std::vector`

The problem remains (it doesn't compile) if a create a specialized template for vectors

```
template <typename T>
std::string stringiy(const std::vector<T> &t)
{
     vector<string> strret = num2str(t);
     string r;
     for ( vector<string>::iterator iter = strret.begin(); iter!=strret.end(); ++iter )
    r.append(*iter);
     return r;
}
```

Any suggestion?

g++-4.5, ubuntu 11.10 amd64

```
In file included from Util.h:41:0,
                 from testLexicalCast.cpp:49:
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::detail::lexical_stream<Target, Source, Traits>::operator<<(const Source&) [with Target = std::basic_string<char>, Source = std::vector<double>, Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’:
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:1151:13:   instantiated from ‘Target boost::detail::lexical_cast(typename boost::call_traits<Source>::param_type, CharT*, size_t) [with Target = std::basic_string<char>, Source = std::vector<double>, bool Unlimited = true, CharT = char, typename boost::call_traits<Source>::param_type = const std::vector<double>&, size_t = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:1174:77:   instantiated from ‘Target boost::lexical_cast(const Source&) [with Target = std::basic_string<char>, Source = std::vector<double>]’
Util.h:211:43:   instantiated from ‘std::string util::stringify(const T&) [with T = std::vector<double>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
testLexicalCast.cpp:72:53:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:595:48: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘((boost::detail::lexical_stream<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<double>, std::char_traits<char> >*)this)->boost::detail::lexical_stream<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<double>, std::char_traits<char> >::stream << input’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:108:7: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:117:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:127:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:165:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:169:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:173:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:180:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:191:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:200:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:204:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:209:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:213:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:221:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:225:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
make: *** [testLexicalCast.o] Error 1
```

Comment: p.s.
I forgot to tell you that I have an overloaded operator << for `std::vector` so the first method with `ostringstream` works

Comment: could you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Could this not be because the actual implementation of vector<T> is more like vector<T,A>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably declared your `operator<<` for vectors in the global namespace, and `boost::lexical_cast` will only look in the `boost::` namespace and in the `std::` namespace, where `ostream` is defined.
Try adding your overload to the `std::` namespace by wrapping your `operator<<` 's declaration and definition in `namespace std { ... }`.

Comment: Yes! You're right, this is definitely the best solution, I wrapped my overloaded operator << into the std namespace and now it works like a charm.

Comment: @111111 Yes, it does, but the argument is a ``std::vector`` and a ``std::ostream``, so ADL looks in the ``std`` namespace.

Comment: @wolfgang, of course that explains it. I don't know what you think but ins't adding to std namespace a little jank (if not illegal)?

Comment: @111111 I think there were a few officially allowed exceptions. I remember for certain that it is specifically allowed to add overloads for std::swap to the std:: namespace, and I *hope* that the same is the case for operator<<.

Comment: @wolfgang: You specialize swap with templates, not provide a new overload as such. The general advise again is to use ADL with swap. I think if it works with adding it to the boost then that would be best. Out of interest do you know when would happen if you aliased vector in a local namespace with the op<< implementation in?

Comment: well, come to think of it, overloading operator<< for std::vector is an illegal hack anyway, but I *do* think it's convenient...

Answer (score 1):

I maybe way off here, but personally I think you would be better off instead of trying to stringify a container that you make a 'serialize' method for all containers.

EDIT: FIXED

```
template<typename Container>
   std::string serialize_container(const Container& container)
{
     std::stringstream ss;
     std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),    
              std::ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(ss,"-"));
     return ss.str();    
}
```

EDIT: that said if you want to use a vector with stringify then you do it like this.

```
template <typename T, typename A=void>
std::string stringiy(const T& t)
{
    //...
} 

template <typename T, typename A>
std::string stringiy(const std::vector<T, A>& container)
{
     std::stringstream ss;

     //if << is overloaded for vector
     ss << container;

     /*//else
     std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
               std::ostream_iterator<T>(ss,"-"));    
     //        std::ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(ss,"-"));
     */
     return ss.str();    
}
```

N.B untested but that is the gist.

Comment: your solution doesn't compile...Util.h: In function ‘std::string util::serialize_container(const T&)’:
Util.h:219:104: error: template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: My bad I used the object rather than the type, see last argument to std::copy.

Comment: perfect, this can do the work, but with this solution I must specify two versions of `stringify` and it doesn't use boost::lexical_cast which when converting from double it has more precision.

In every case your is a good answer, thanks!

Comment: Does make sense to differentiate the template input type statically from container or built in type?

Comment: I personally prefer to use value_type, templates are great but too many and they become confusing. That said if you want to ensure that the function only takes a vector of any type then your going to have to have T and A anyway, in which case use them because they are more concise and less verbose - just `T` rather than `typename Container::value_type`

Comment: change second example to show just `T` rather than `typename Container::value_type` might make it clearer.